# Looping through tenants using MSAL.js

Tags: javascript, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I am using **MSAL.js** to use log in and use the Graph API.

The Azure AD app I have created is a multi-tenant and has the correct permissions when running against a particular tenant so I can confirm this works.

The hurdle is I want to be able to loop through all of our tenants to obtain any data available in the graph API.

I have attempted to simply change the config of the MSAL connection however this fails and will use the existing `authority` value every call.

After this I created a `forEach` array with the `tenantid` for it to loop through however this yielded the same result.

I created a logout function that was called each time however this wants to redirect you away from your page to your logout address.

My code:

```
function config_app(tenantid, callback, apiUrl) {
    var applicationConfig = {
        auth: {
            clientId: "XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX",
            authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenantid,
            redirectUri: "https://my.redirecturi.com/fake"
        },
        cache: {
            cacheLocation: "sessionStorage",
            storeAuthStateInCookie: false
        }
    };
    var msalInstance = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(applicationConfig);
    callback(tenantid, applicationConfig, msalInstance, callMSGraph, apiUrl);
}
function sign_in(tenantid, applicationConfig, msalInstance, callback, apiUrl) {
    var scopes = {
        scopes: ["Organization.Read.All"],
        loginHint: "my@email.com"
    };
    msalInstance.acquireTokenSilent(scopes).then(response => {
        callback(response.accessToken, graphAPICallback, apiUrl);
    }).catch(err => {
    });
}
function callMSGraph(accessToken, callback, apiUrl) {
    console.log("calling ms graph");
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
            callback(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
    }
    xmlHttp.open("GET", "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/" + apiUrl, true);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
    xmlHttp.send();
}
function graphAPICallback(data) {
    $('#o365res').append(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
}
config_app('XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX', sign_in, 'organization');
```

I attempted to add a few tenant ID's into an array and loop through using:

```
var clients = ['XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX','YYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYY'];
clients.forEach(function(e) {
    config_app(e, sign_in, 'organization');
});
```

After much reading it seems I cannot use the logout function without the redirect, I'd much rather be able to simply change the tenant via the `authority` value and jump across anyway with the same token.

I am using `MSAL v1.2.0`

I'm hoping to pull all Organization data from our tenants to display on a single page, then to later expand this to pull secure scores and any other valuable data from the API.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After liaising with the kind devs for MSAL.js I worked through my solution.

GitHub issues:

[My original issue](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/1289)

[They said it was related/duplicate of this](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/1225)

However I found that by simplifying the function and adding `forceRefresh: true,` to the scopes, each pass managed to change authority and pull the required data.

Here are my functions:

```
function getData(tenantid,apiUrl) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        var applicationConfig = {
            auth: {
                clientId: "AZURE-APP-ID-HERE",
                authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenantid,
                redirectUri: "https://my.redirect.uri/uri"
            },
            cache: {
                cacheLocation: "localStorage",
                storeAuthStateInCookie: false
            }
        };
        var msalInstance = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(applicationConfig);
        var scopes = {
            forceRefresh: true,
            scopes: ["Organization.Read.All"],
            loginHint: "user@email.com"
        };
        msalInstance.acquireTokenSilent(scopes).then(response => {
            var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                    $('#o365res').append(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
                    resolve();
                }
            }
            xmlHttp.open("GET", "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/" + apiUrl, true);
            xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + response.accessToken);
            xmlHttp.send();
        }).catch(err => { });
    });
}
function getDataChain(clients) {
    const nextClient = clients.shift();
    if (nextClient) {
        return getData(nextClient,'organization').then(_ => getDataChain(clients))
    } else { return Promise.resolve(); }
}
```

Followed by my client ID array and calling the chain function:

```
var clients = ['XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX','YYY-YYY-YYY-YYY-YYY'];
getDataChain(clients).then(_ => console.log("all finished"));
```